# angularJS about how to use service in every .js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I define some `service` in `app1.js`
like this

**app1.js**

```
  angular.module('todoApp.services', []).factory('TodoService', function($http, $location) {
  ┊ return {
  ┊ ┊ send: function(url, par) {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ return $http.get(url, {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ params: par
  ┊ ┊ ┊ });
  ┊ ┊ },
  ┊ ┊ get_default_data: function($scope, url, par) {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ this.send(url, par).success(function(data) {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ $scope.data = data;
  ┊ ┊ ┊ });
  ┊ ┊ },
  ┊ ┊ change_status: function($scope, url, par) {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ this.send(url, par).success(function() {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item) {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ if (item.id === par.sid) {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ item.status = par.status;
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ }
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ });
  ┊ ┊ ┊ });
  ┊ ┊ },
    })
```

and how can I use this `todoApp.services` in another `.js` file?
I use like this

**app2.js**

```
angular.module('myapp', ['todoApp.services'])
```

It doesn't work, how can I use it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Did you include your service-js file?

Answer (score 2):

As per your current implementation you have declared `todoApp.services` module with a factory in it and you have defined the dependency of `todoApp.services` for `myapp` which prefect.

However you should return  promise from service rather than manipulating `$scope`

```
angular.module('todoApp.services', []).factory('TodoService', function($http, $location) {
    return {
        get_default_data: function() {
            return $http.get(url, par)
        }
    }
})
```

To use you have to injcet the service to your contoller

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['TodoService', '$scope', function(TodoService, $scope){

    //Call the service method
    TodoService.get_default_data().then(function(){
        $scope.data = data;
    });     
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just link the service off of your app module and then inject the service into controllers with DI.

app.js

```
(function() {

    angular.module('app', []);

})();
```

app.services.js

```
(function() {

    function appService() {
        // service code
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .factory('appService', appService);        

})();
```

app.controller.js

```
(function() {

    function appController(appService) {
        // controller code
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('appController', appController);        

})();
```

this will give you your factory data inside your controller.

Comment: I must write them in one file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.factory('myService', function() {
        return {
            myFunction: function() {
                alert("I'm foo!");
            }
        };
    });
```

Define service at rootscope.

```
    myApp.run(function($rootScope, myService) {
        $rootScope.appData = myService;
    });
```

access service at any controller :

```
    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.appData.myFunction();
    }]);
```

Comment: Attaching stuff to $rootScope is just bad practice

Comment: you do not need to attach the service to rootScope. This is also a bad practice as you want to use rootScope as minimal as possible. Just setting the factory off of the app module and injecting it into controllers is enough to pass it around the application.